# undetermined string literal error

Tags: php, javascript

How do I fix this unterminated string literal error. What does this error mean and how can it be fixed

Below is the full code:

```
    <?php
    session_start();

if(isset($_POST['fileImage'])){

$idx = count($_POST ['fileImage']) -1 ;
$output = isset($_POST ['fileImage'][$idx]) ? $_POST ['fileImage'][$idx]['name'] : "";

}

    ?>


    function stopImageUpload(success) {

        var imageNameArray = ['<?php echo  json_encode($output); ?>'];
        var result = '';

        if (success == 1) {
            result = '<span class="msg">The file was uploaded successfully!</span><br/><br/>';
            for (var i = 0; i < imageNameArray.length; i++) {
                $('.listImage').append(imageNameArray[i] + '<br/>');
            }
        }
        else {
            result = '<span class="emsg">There was an error during file upload!</span><br/><br/>';
        }

        return true;
    }​
```

Comment: Sorry, but are you placing that JavaScript in an external file, or within the HTML document you are returning?

Comment: It is on a seperate page from the php script I am trying to $_POST

Comment: Remove the single quotes around `<?php echo json_encode(); ?>`.

Comment: @DCoder I did try this previously but it now gives me an invalid regular expression flag w error : undefined variable: $output.

Comment: That means the variable `$output` is undefined (shocking!). That can happen when your `if(isset($_POST['fileImage']))` check fails - you should add an `else` and handle it there.

Comment: Well I want nothing to happen if it fails, I tried else{ echo "";} after isset but it still displays same error. Also if you want to put you comment as an answer  will mark it when the problem is fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better solution might look like this:

```
<?php
session_start();

$results = array();
if(isset($_POST['fileImage'])){
  // not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve here
  // so just replicating the logic you already had
  // but I'm sure there's a better way to do whatever this is trying to do
  $idx = count($_POST['fileImage']) -1 ;
  $results[] = isset($_POST['fileImage'][$idx]) ? $_POST ['fileImage'][$idx]['name'] : "";
}

?>

function stopImageUpload(success) {
  var imageNameArray = <?php echo json_encode($results); ?>;
  var result = '';

  if (success == 1) {
    result = '<span class="msg">The file was uploaded successfully!</span><br/><br/>';
    for (var i = 0; i < imageNameArray.length; i++) {
      $('.listImage').append(imageNameArray[i] + '<br/>');
    }
  } else {
    result = '<span class="emsg">There was an error during file upload!</span><br/><br/>';
  }

  // you might want to use the "result" variable before returning

  return true;
}​
```

What changed? I removed the `[]` around the output of `json_encode` and made the array in PHP instead of JS. This way, when you do post the form, `$results` will be an array with a single element, and when you don't, it'll be an empty array. The rest of the logic should work just like before, but do read the comments I added.

Answer (score 2):

It means that there's something wrong with your quotes (an extra single quote in the echo'd content, or a line feed) and it's messing up the parser. Make sure any characters that are special in JS (quotes, line breaks etc) are properly escaped.

`json_encode` does this for you.

Comment: @userrandomnumbers: Did you already read the manual to see what it does?

Comment: I know it is something wrong with the quotes, but the wierd thing is that before the isset code you see at top, it was working fine. Also I tried putting json_encode code in a couple of places but still keeps giving me same error

Comment: @userrandomnumbers: Paste the offending part as seen by your browser in your post (use View source)

Comment: I thought I mentioned it in question but this is where it is pointed to: `var imageNameArray = ['<br />`

Comment: @userrandomnumbers: But you didn't post all of it.

Comment: No because in the error console it stops it after the <br/>, anyway the line I posted in the previous comment is what it is showing in the page source

Comment: @userrandomnumbers: Surely the `']` is in there somewhere? At any rate, even a line break will break it, so put json_encode around $output when echoing it.

Comment: This is one of the things I tried previously, I tried the json_encode(); again around $output like you said but it still displays the same error, I updated code above